# How to send notification to users when approached expiration time (yearly)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an invoice model. I trying if approached expiration time send notification to users but I don't know how does it.

My table:

```
| service_name | start_date(date) | notification_at(date) |
|:-------------|-----------------:|:---------------------:|
| example      | 2018-08-01       |         NULL          |
```

I want to 30 days before every year send notification to user if specified start_date is set a date. So send notification when now is `2019-07-1` .How I can checking every day with `schedule` in Laravel ?

I tried case:

`Invoice::whereNotNull('start_date')->whereDate('start_date','....');`

Comment: Are you having trouble with the query or actually setting up a way to make sure users are notified 30 days before the `start_date`? Writing a query is easy but the latter will require a cron job of some sort.

Comment: No I haven't any setting up a way for users. But I want to without it. Yes I want to checking query with cron job every day. But I don't make a sql query for it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you are interacting with a database then at some point SQL **must** be produced. Laravel Eloquent simply hides SQL from you. `Invoice::whereNotNull('start_date')->whereDate('start_date','....');` is ultimately SQL.

Comment: Anyway, I have an idea in my mind I will try it. If it works I give your answer. Thank you for answer and I'm sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLVED

Actually, the scenarios I wanted to do were these. For examples,

- It should be first send notification date is `2019-07-01` (30 days before every year)
- It should be second send notification date is `2019-07-15` (15 days before every year)
- It should be third send notification date is `2019-07-26` (5 days before every year)
- And always should be repeat these steps as next year

I found the solution like this. Firstly, I did modified My Table like this.

```
| service_name | start_date(date) | next_notification_date(date) | next_add_day(int) |
|:-------------|-----------------:|:----------------------------:|:-----------------:|
| example      | 2018-08-01       |             NULL             |        NULL       |
```

And I create a command class to the process.

**ExpirationCommand.php**

```
public function handle()
{
        $now = Carbon::now();

        Invoice::whereNotNull('start_date')->whereDate('next_notification_date', $now->format('Y-m-d'))->each(function ($invoice) use ($now) {
            // defines
            $addDay = $invoice->next_add_day;
            $addYear = 365 - 30 - 15 - 5;

            // send notification
            event(new ExpirationInvoiceEvent($invoice->project,$invoice->next_notification_date->diffInDays($now)));

            // setup db
            if ( ! $addDay || $addDay === $addYear) {
                $addDay = 30;
            } elseif ($addDay !== 15 && $addDay !== 5) {
                $addDay = 15;
            } elseif ($addDay !== 5) {
                $addDay = 5;
            } else {
                $addDay = $addYear;
            }

            $invoice->update([
                'next_notification_date' => $now->addDay($addDay)->format('Y-m-d'),
                'next_add_day'           => $addDay,
            ]);
        });
}
```

And finally I add command in the **Console\Kernel.php** for control twice in day

```
$schedule->command('expiration-control')->twiceDaily();
```